# Caesar Cipher technique and reverse case in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hash, caesar-cipher

I am beginner and want to make my own function.
I want to hash the password by shifting every character by given x
positions and reverse to lowercase/uppercase.

I think the code below should return "EFGH7654" but it return 55 with no error message.
How can I fix it? Is it because of I put a function in a function?
Or I type wrong any thing?

```js
function hashPassword(password, x) {
  // password is a string, x is a number
  // return a string
  // (ex. password = 'ab1By', x = 3 so it should return "DE4eB")
  function shift(text, s) {
    result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      let char = text[i];
      if (char.toUpperCase(text[i])) {
        let ch = String.fromCharCode((char.charCodeAt(0) + s - 65) % 26 + 65);
        result += ch;
      } else {
        let ch = String.fromCharCode((char.charCodeAt(0) + s - 97) % 26 + 97);
        result += ch;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function reversecase(x) {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
      var character = x[i];
      if (character == character.toLowerCase()) {
        // The character is lowercase
        output = output + character.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        // The character is uppercase
        output = output + character.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    return output
  }

  var str = "";
  var result = "";
  var charcode = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    if (typeof password[i] === typeof str) {
      char = shift(password[i], x)
      charcode = reversecase(char)
      result += charcode;
    } else {
      num = password[i] + x
      number = num % 10
      result += number.toString()
    }
  }
  return result
};
console.log(hashPassword("abcd4321", 4))
```

Comment: `reverse to lowercase/uppercase` - If so, shoudn't the expected output be `EFGH7654`

Answer (score 0):

There a quite some problems in your code.

The first problem here is not only the nesting, but the fact that you're defining the `result` variable in the outer function scope using the `var` keyword. Then you use (read/write) that variable in different places.

1. In function `shift()` (also in `return` statement)
2. In the outer function (also in `return` statement)

The thing you have to understand is, that you're referring to the *same* variable `result` every time. To ensure that your variables are scoped, i.e. are only valid within a block (`if` statement, `function` body, etc.), you should use the `let` or `const` keywords. This makes your code a lot safer.

The second problem are some assumptions you make regarding data types. If you have a string `let s = "my string 123"`, the expression `typeof s[x] === 'string'` will be `true` for every `x` in `s`.

Another problem is the algorithm itself. The outer function `hashPassword()` iterates over all characters of the input string. Within that loop you call function `shift(password[i], x)`, passing a single character. The first parameter of `shift()` is called `text` - and there is another `for` loop (which is confusing and does not make sense).

To make things short, please have a look at this simplified version:

```js
function shift(char, x) {
    let result;
    
    const code = char.charCodeAt(0);
    if (code >= 65 && code < 91) {
      result = String.fromCharCode((code + x - 65) % 26 + 65);
    }
    else if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
      result = String.fromCharCode((code + x - 48) % 10 + 48);
    }
    else {
      result = String.fromCharCode((code + x - 97) % 26 + 97);
    }
    
    return result;
}

function reverseCase(character) {
  if (character === character.toLowerCase()) {
    return character.toUpperCase();
  } 
  else {
    return character.toLowerCase();
  }
}

function hashPassword(password, x) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    const char = shift(password[i], x);
    result += reverseCase(char);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(hashPassword("abcd4321", 4)); // Output: EFGH8765
```